# Sails.js + socket.io: Sending messages from server to clients

Tags: node.js, sockets, sails.js

I'm attempting to set up a system with sails.js to have the server broadcast messages to a set of clients. Basically:

1. A client in Group A sends an AJAX request to the server.
2. The server processes the request and sends a message through socket to all clients of Group B.
3. The clients of Group B receive the message through the socket and display something.

According to the socket.io documentation, I should be able to have the clients in Group B join a "room", and then have the server broadcast to that specific room, but on the client side, the preexisting "socket" doesn't have the method "socket.join('room')". So, I tried just sending a unique event to all clients:

```
socket.on("connect", function(){
  console.log("Client Connected");
});

socket.on("my_event", function(data){
  console.log("my_event received");
});
```

This works fine by doing "sails.io.sockets.emit("my_event", {...})" on the server side, but isn't this sending the event to every single client? I could make the event name unique, something like "my_event_000" with an ID to specify the group, but that would still be sending events to every client unnecessarily.

Should I be using "rooms"? And if so, how?

Answer (score 4):

The Sails way to do this would be to have a model backing your "Groups", and in a controller action have a socket subscribe to a group with `Group.subscribe(groupId, req.socket)`.  Then you can send messages to a specific group with `Group.publish(groupId, data)`.

You can also subscribe to an arbitrary room name in a controller using `req.listen(groupId)`, and broadcast to that room with `req.broadcast(roomName, data)`.

This is all in the [Sails documentation for working with Sockets](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/0.9/sockets.md)!

Comment: Can you provide more specific example please. Some more code will be useful. Can't seem to find the Group thing in the link provided.

Comment: Group is the name of the model in the example.  In the docs they're listed as `Model.subscribe`, `Model.publish`, etc.