# Sails.js to client using sails.sockets.join and sails.sockets.broadcast doesn't return info to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

I'm attempting to create a one to one chat using Sails.js and sails.io.js on the client side.

I can get the `io.socket.get` and `io.socket.post` to work, but I haven't been able to receive anything from either `sails.sockets.broadcast` or `Model.publish` as instructed here:

[Personalized chat using Sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511887/personalized-chat-using-sails-js)

or here

[Sails.js + socket.io: Sending messages from server to clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648187/sails-js-socket-io-sending-messages-from-server-to-clients)

**Server Side Code:**

UserController.js

```
module.exports = {
    listen: function(req, res) {
        console.log("about to join " + userId);
        sails.sockets.join(req.socket, req.param('userId'));
    }
};
```

From: http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/sails.sockets/sails.sockets.join.html

MessageController.js

```
// Some code to get userId and message model here

console.log("about to broadcast on " + userId);
sails.sockets.broadcast(userId, 'conversation_message', message); 

// Did not JSONify the message model, not sure if I need to?
```

From: http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/sails.sockets/sails.sockets.broadcast.html

**Client Side Code:**

```
// Some code to get userId...

io.socket.get('/user/listen', {
    userId: userId
}, function() {
    io.socket.on('conversation_message', function(message) {
        console.log("we have a message");
    });
});
```

When I hit the route that triggers the broadcast with `userId`, nothing is sent to this client code to log `we have a message`. Any ideas?

*I have tried the Model.subscribe / Model.publish methods as well with no luck--same issue.*

**Update:** The `listen` function doesn't actually return -- as someone suggested in a comment that they later deleted. Adding `res.send(200);` to the end of the `listen` function was enough to make it work.

If that person would add their comment again as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(That was me. I thought my comment might of been not worthwhile because i reread your post and you said you had the get working so I thought I was wrong. My comment was something to the effect below, but I don't remember verbatim)

Have you checked to make sure the you are actually getting a response on the client-side listen? What log statements are you actually getting throughout your code? Put a console.log('get user listen') or something inside of the Client-side socket.get.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I didn't catch that sooner. Yes I had taken the not failing as an indication of it working but clearly not haha.